# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите,какой знак поставить после "не знал". Предложение: "Я не знал () отдавать ли ему ключи, можно ли ему доверять".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Я не знал , отдавать ли ему ключи, можно ли ему доверять".- запятая отделяет придаточные изъяснительные от главного. Тире здесь, думаю, неуместно, ведь инверсии нет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Частица ЛИ используется в придаточном изъяснительном. Некоторых смущает отсутствие привычного союза.

Comment: "Ли", как и "же" может выступать в роли не только частицы, но и союза

Comment: А можно пример с "ЖЕ"?

Comment: Он пошел направо, я же (=а) налево. Слово  ЖЕ здесь является сочинительным противительным союзом.

Comment: Является или выступает в роли?